# The Summation of x(log(log(x))

Tags: calculus, summation

So I would like to know if it is possible to express this summation in terms of $n$:

$$\sum_{x=2}^n x\log(\log(x))$$

For example the summation below is equivalent to $\frac12 n (n+1)$ in terms of $n$

$$\sum_{x=0}^nx=\frac12n(n+1)$$

Comment: Make $n=3$ and your summation is $2 \log (\log (2))+3 \log (\log (3))$ which has no chances to look as a rational number.

Comment: One can produce an *approximation* that might be useful, but a nice closed form is too much to expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some logarithm identities to achieve a little progress, but I would be surprised if there is anything better.
$$\sum\limits_{x=2}^nx\log(\log(x))=\sum\limits_{x=2}^n\log(\log^x(x))=\log\left(\prod\limits_{x=2}^n\log^x(x)\right)$$

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but other than beauty see no  additional use: Note:

$$\sum{x = 2}^{n}[x\log(\log(x))] = \sum_{x = 2}^{n}[\log(\log(x)^x)] $$

Now we reduce this to a product

$$ \log \left(\prod_{x = 2}^{n} \log(x)^x \right) $$

Now the internal product itself can be factored using the original product to power rule

The end result is a strange power tower like structure

$$ \log\left(\log\left(2^{\log \left( 3^{\log \left( 4^{\log \left(5^{\vdots} \right)^5} \right)^4} \right)^3}\right)^2\right) $$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas. Beauty is part of mathematics and what you gave is really beautiful. Thanks & cheers :-)